# How can I get luminance from dslr?

Tags: opencv

I have been trying to obtain the image brightness in Opencv and to try get the luminance However, I feel dizzy 
Is it possible to obtain luminance from the pixel brigtness?
Could you please help me with a method or algorithm, that can be realised through OpenCv
Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: if by luminance you mean the L channel of the HSL color space use cvtColor with CV_BGR2HLS (but it won't create the heat map you posted...)

Comment: I found [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880635/get-luminance-values-from-camera)

Comment: HSL L channel means relative value