# How to Get luminance values from camera

Tags: opencv

I have been trying to obtain the image brightness in Opencv and to try get the luminance

I already got the values from the Y channel of YCbCr. I just need a way/function to convert this into standard units like cd/m2

The values range from 0-255. The problem is that these are relative values.

Could you please help me with a method or algorithm

I found the app(Photolux) which can measure luminance

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get luminance from dslr?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28467284/how-can-i-get-luminance-from-dslr)

Comment: You should edit your previous question with the additional information instead of asking a new question.